# Toaster not hiding - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular2-toaster

I am using [angular2-toaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster) but I am having issues ONLY on this project. I used it on multiple projects before and it works fine, but when I switched to angular 5 version I cannot get the toaster message to disappear. On success or error, I have a timeout which should hide the message, however it doesn't happen. This is my toaster config, if anyone had the same issue recently let me know, thanks!

```
if (showSuccessToast) {
        const toast: Toast = {
          type: 'success',
          title: 'Well Done !',
          body: toastMessage ? toastMessage : 'Operation successful.',
          showCloseButton: true,
          timeout: 2000,
          closeHtml: '<div class="toaster-close-icon"></div>'
        };

        this.toasterService.pop(toast);
      }
```

Comment: is the library compatible with angular 5.x.x?

Comment: Do you mean that the toaster is loaded successfully but has problem only while hiding the message or is there  problem on loading it too on console?

Comment: @NirajPaudel It pops, but doesn't hide the message

Comment: I also facing the same problem in angular 4. Toaster message pops successfully but it is not being hidden automatically after defined timeout.

Comment: @NemanjaGrabovac there is a new version of the library out.  Does it solve your problem or does the issue still persist?

Comment: @DavidL check out my answer below.

Comment: @ruchit07 Check out my answer if u still have this issue

Comment: @NemanjaGrabovac Thanks. I have already resolved this from myself.

Comment: @NemanjaGrabovac which toaster version you have installed with angular 5 , would you like to mention/refer please .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see in the documentation there is a point: `Version ^ 5.0.0 requires either .forRoot() or .forChild() ToasterModule inclusion.`

Could you try to add `.forRoot()` for `ToasterModule`? `forRoot` guarantees that you create service instances only once. So it might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with just removing all the custom settings, for some reason it wouldn't work with 2 sec timeout... Idk, for all other pojects it worked, for this one it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any stuck msg you can clear them all by using `this.toaster.clear();`

```
  showMsg(type, msg, time) {
    this.toaster.pop(type, msg, '');
    setTimeout(() => {
          this.toaster.clear();
    }, time)
  }
```

or by specifying [toastId and toastContainerId to clear function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster) `this.toasterService.clear(toast.toastId, toast.toastContainerId)`

```
var toast = this.toasterService.pop('success', 'title', 'body');
this.toasterService.clear(toast.toastId, toast.toastContainerId)
```